# How to create really empty project in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Documentation says to choose

File | New Project | Empty

but this is not true, because after this procedure a dialog appears, insisting me to define modules

[image]

and I don't see any option to create empty or dummy module.

If I just press `OK`, I got a project, where I can't create files, even textual:

[image]

So, is it possible to create a project, where I could create files of my own?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add at least one module. If not importing, using Static Web seems to be the most empty modulte template